# How to set "void" public?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have for example this method:

```
-(void)customSum {
NSLog(@"show something");
}
```

in HomeView.m and I want to call that method in all other files, for example in ArticleView.m. Can I do something like:

```
[HomeView customSum];
```

or something similar? How can I do that?

Comment: How do you mean, 'to be available'? So `ArticleView.m` can implement it, or call it?

Comment: Call it from ArticleView.m. In ArticleView.m I've include HomeView.m

Comment: Please take a look at my improved question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't sound like are trying to subclass anything (which would be why people are mentioning inheritance).  If you are, than see the other answers.

The obj-c way to do this would be the following: you want to have HomeView.h declare an interface for a class HomeView, and have the method be either a class method or an instance method.  Like so:

```
    @interface HomeView : UIView
    - (void)anInstanceMethod;
    + (void)aClassMethod;
    @end
```

I'm assuming since these are"views" you are deriving from UIView.
Then you would have HomeView.m implementing the method:

```
    @implementation HomeView
    - (void)anInstanceMethod
    {
        // Do Something
    }
    + (void)aClassMethod
    {
        // Do Something else
    }
    @end
```

Then, in ArticlViewe.m (Where you have an implementation of a class ArticleView declared in ArticleView.h (This is the standard way to do it, though you can put in an interface in a .m file, but you don't wan't to include a .m file, so the class wouldn't be visible outside the file).

```
    #include "HomeView.h"

    ...
        [HomeView aClassMethod]; // Call the class method on the class
        HomeView *homeView = [HomeView new];
        [homeView anInstanceMethod]; // Call the instance method on an instance
    ...
```

If this is all new to you, you should probably get a book on Objective-C and iOS development.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should read [something about Inheritance](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Inheritance).

Answer (score 1):

You'd first have to create an instance of `HomeView`, like this:

```
HomeView *view = [[HomeView alloc]init];
```

You can then call this method from anywhere you like, like this:

```
[view customSum];
```

If you want to call this method without having to create an instance of `HomeView`, you can make it a class method instead of an instance method by changing the `-` to a `+`, like so:

```
+(void)customSum {
    NSLog(@"show something");
}
```

Now, you can call it from anywhere, like this:

```
[HomeView customSum];
```

However, make sure you have declared this method in your `HomeView.h` file and you have imported that header file in the file you want to call this method from, like this:

```
#import "HomeView.h"
```

For more information about the Objective-C programming language, I'd recommend you read [the Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `ArticleView` derives from `HomeView`, you can simply call `[self customSum]` from within `ArticleView`.

Within `ArticleView`, you can also override the `HomeView` implementation of `-customSum` if need be.